# Fast alternative to sscanf

Tags: c, parsing, embedded

I'm writing a parser for a text file on an embedded system in C. I need to use the sscanf function hundreds of times each second which creates performance trouble. Therefore, I'm trying to find a fast alternative to sscanf.

The text file I need to parse contains parameters of the form "parameter=%d,%d,%d,%d". The parameter names vary in length, but the parameters always consist of 4 integer values.

The parser reads one line of the text file after the other and stores the string in the variable "token". The variable "format" contains the strings of the form "parameter=%d,%d,%d,%d".

```
void Parser_GetQuadToken( char* token, const char* format, int16_t* res1, int16_t* res2, int16_t* res3, int16_t* res4 )
{
    uint32_t var1, var2, var3, var4;
    sscanf( token, format, &var1, &var2, &var3, &var4 ) );
    *res1 = var1;
    *res2 = var2;
    *res3 = var3;
    *res4 = var4;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to implement a fast alternative?

Comment: Change `format` and assign directly to arguments? `if (sscanf(token, format, res1, res2, res3, res4) != 4) /* error */;`

Comment: Have you profiled to see that this routine is the bottleneck rather than, say, the I/O?

Comment: If this is really coming from a file, I'm not-at-all convinced the file IO isn't the bottleneck rather the this sscanf.

Comment: @pmg: Thanks. Unfortunately, format can't be changed as it is a fixed specification. However, I'll try assigning directly to arguments.

Comment: @stark: Thanks. As far as I know, the speed of the file I/O limits how fast the variable "token" can be read in, i.e. how fast the parser can progress to the next line. For each given line, the parser calls the Parser_GetQuadToken function hundreds of times. When I remove most of the calls of Parser_GetQuadToken, the parsing process is much faster.

Comment: @Hermetica: beware changing arguments and keeping the same format. `scanf("%" SCNu32, &var32);` is not compatible with `scanf("%" SCNu32, &var16);`

Comment: Why convert hundreds of times? Convert once and save the values.

Comment: You could also pass shorter strings: pass `token+10` (skipping "parameter=") and a format of just "%d,%d,%d,%d" - that could speed things up a bit.

Comment: You might have better luck using `strchr` to find the `=`, then repeatedly calling `strtol` to convert digits.  `strtol` gives you back a pointer to the first digit character you didn't convert, and you can check if it's a `,` and, if so, loop and convert again.

Comment: Or if function call overhead is an issue, you could do it all my hand, marching a `char *` pointer through the string, looking for `=` and digits and `,` and rolling your own inline `atoi`.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what the format of the input is before you can optimize. Does it have negative numbers? Is it decimal? Hex? What is the target? 8 bit? 32 bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sscanf()` has to both interpret the format string match it to your `token` and convert the string content.  You can avoid the unnecessary format string parse by using a direct conversion function such as `atoi()`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Parser_GetQuadToken( const char* token, int16_t* res1, int16_t* res2, int16_t* res3, int16_t* res4 )
{
    char* resstr = strchr( token, '=' ) + 1 ;
    *res1 = (int16_t)atoi( resstr ) ;

    resstr = strchr( resstr, ',' ) + 1 ;
    *res2 = (int16_t)atoi( resstr ) ;

    resstr = strchr( resstr, ',' ) + 1 ;
    *res3 = (int16_t)atoi( resstr ) ;

    resstr = strchr( resstr, ',' ) + 1 ;
    *res4 = (int16_t)atoi( resstr ) ;
}
```

Since the aim is to improve performance, you need to measure the improvement.  I measured it at 9 times faster in a 64bit debug build in VC++, and 12 times faster for 32 bit code. YMMV for your target and compiler.  Optimisation has little impact as it is bound in the library code.

Note that the above implementation has as much error checking as the original code - i.e. none.  You need to be certain the input `token` is going to be valid as a pre-condition.  In my test adding error checking had little impact on performance:

```
bool Parser_GetQuadToken( const char* token, int16_t* res1, int16_t* res2, int16_t* res3, int16_t* res4 )
{
    char* resstr = 0 ;
    if( (resstr = strchr( token, '=' )) != NULL )
    {
        *res1 = (int16_t)atoi( ++resstr ) ;

        if( (resstr = strchr( resstr, ',' )) != NULL )
        {
            *res2 = (int16_t)atoi( ++resstr ) ;

            if( (resstr = strchr( resstr, ',' )) != NULL )
            {
                *res3 = (int16_t)atoi( ++resstr ) ;

                if( (resstr = strchr( resstr, ',' )) != NULL )
                {
                    *res4 = (int16_t)atoi( ++resstr ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return resstr != NULL ;
}
```

It may not have the impact you expect however - the file I/O will be far slower than the memory and string manipulation imposed by `sscanf()` - the issue with `sscanf()` in embedded systems is more normally the code space and stack usage required.

@SteveSummit has suggested using `strtol()`.  Since this keeps track of the "last position" scanned, to avoid reiteration of the string.  You can exploit this to omit the explicit search for the comma delimiters:

```
void Parser_GetQuadToken( const char* token, int16_t* res1, int16_t* res2, int16_t* res3, int16_t* res4 )
{
    char* resstr = strchr( token, '=' ) ;
    *res1 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 ) ;
    *res2 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 ) ;
    *res3 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 ) ;
    *res4 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 ) ;
}
```

In my tests this is about 12 time faster in debug and 17 in optimisation - it is somewhat variable testing on Windows however.  I'll leave error checking for you to consider.

Comment: By calling `strchr` and then `atoi`, you're needlessly scanning everything twice.  Why not use `strtol`?

Comment: @Clifford: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot. It's approximately 10 times faster on my embedded system.

Comment: In addition, `atoi` doesn't have error handling so it shouldn't be used regardless. Use `strtol`, or better, `strtoul` if negative numbers aren't necessary.

Comment: @Lundin since performance was the key here, and the original code performed no checks, I have deliberately left the error checking to the OP. In the case that the input has been checked prior to this it may be that checks are redundant. GIGO. It is measurbly and significantly faster. _My_ work here is done.  Your advice should if course be considered.

Comment: `strto...` is going to have pretty much equivalent performance to `atoi`, but the latter is generally unsafe and shouldn't be used for that reason.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, in fact it is slightly faster as Steve pointed out and I have documented in this answer.  The strtol solution was added at Steve's suggestion, and had it occurred to me in the first place, I'd have used it as the only solution. However the point about omitting the format string parse is the major performance gain, and I had already worked up that argument and taken measurements with that.  I chose not to spend more of my time refining it.  I did the heavy lifting here, feel free to post a derivative answer. ;-)

Comment: `atoi` is also not too fast... at least the one provided with gcc.
You can improve on that. See here - https://github.com/yb303/swar

Comment: @BitWhistler The thrust of this answer was that sscanf is particularly slow, and atoi 9 times faster, and strtol 12 times faster (in my tests), and both more appropriate to the task. If you have a superior solution you should post an answer.  that would allow you to include your own metrics, rather than taking it on trust that it is in fact better. My aim was not to find the fastest possible solution, but rather a more appropriate solution that is as a consequence faster.

Comment: @Clifford, I really don't see how atoi, or strtol, more appropriate than sscanf, except that it's faster.
And since we're after performance here, IMHO you may as well go after the most performant version of atoi.
My SWAR atoi is at least x10 faster than the gcc atoi. Even a naive atoi you write in 5 minutes is much faster than the gcc one.
I do not wish to write a new answer because I think your answer is good. It provides the correct direction to fixing the issue and it's been a long time since it was accepted.

Comment: @BitWhistler Then perhaps you have not read or understood my answer. These functions are specialist in that the _only_ convert a string to an integer, which is specifically what the OP requires. scanf on the other hand is _generalist_ and can do a lot more that is not required here. The generalist nature is what makes it slower.

Comment: @Clifford, everything you say about sscanf is true, but it is also true for printf, atoi, etc.

If you'd re-implement the general sscanf yourself you'd see it is still a lot faster than the stock impl. The big performance hit in all these functions doesn't come from parsing "%s", but from something else. I know because I have re-implemented printf and sscanf before.

So if I haven't made it clear so far - you do punch in the right direction, but not all the way. You did "step 1" and replaced sscanf, but you could continue and do "step 2" and replace atoi for the exact same justification.

Comment: @BitWhistler This is a pointless discussion, and you have missed the point. That being that a specialist function that does only what you need and no more will be computationally simpler and generally faster.  It is not about a specific implementation.  Really, if you feel that strongly about it, post an answer as I suggested - we might all learn something interesting.