# Optimizing a text file parser for speed

Tags: c, file, parsing, text

I'm writing a function for parsing a text file in C. The text file contains thousands of parameters of the following form:

```
parameter=1,6,3,6
another_parameter=1,45,2,3
```

In order to parse the text file line by line, I'm using the answer to the question
[Fast alternative to sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778829/fast-alternative-to-sscanf)

Using the code below, it is already possible to parse the text file quickly. However, I'm looking to further improve it for speed. Does anyone have a suggestion what could be further optimized?

```
void ConfigReader_ScanInt16x4 (const char *token, const char *format, int16_t *res1, int16_t *res2, int16_t *res3, int16_t *res4)
{
    int stop = 0;
    char* resstr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (token[i] != format[i])
        {
            stop = 1;
            break;
        }
        if(token[i] == '=')
        {
            resstr = strchr( token, '=' );
            break;
        }
    }
    if(stop == 0)
    {
            *res1 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 );
            *res2 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 );
            *res3 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 );
            *res4 = (int16_t)strtol( ++resstr, &resstr, 10 );
            stop2 = 1;
    }
}
```

To parse the text file, I go through it line by line and call the function to parse the current line which is contained in token:

```
ConfigReader_ScanInt16x4(token, "parameter=%d,%d,%d,%d", (int16_t*) &parameter[0], (int16_t*) &parameter[1], (int16_t*) &parameter[2], (int16_t*) &parameter[3]);
ConfigReader_ScanInt16x4(token, "another_parameter=%d,%d,%d,%d", (int16_t*) &another_parameter[0], (int16_t*) &another_parameter[1], (int16_t*) &another_parameter[2], (int16_t*) &another_parameter[3]);
```

Comment: Do you know, that this is the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: @JCWasmx86: Yes, I tested it.

Comment: Do you have any sort of benchmark for us, so we can speak about the same input to compare performance?

Comment: @JCWasmx86: I'm running the code on an embedded system. Calling ConfigReader_ScanInt16x4 approximately 100 times for each line takes 150 µs. In addition to that, it takes 100 µs to read the line.

Comment: You can combine reading from the file and parsing the data into one, so you don't have to effectively look at every character twice (Once when reading to find a newline, once when parsing that line).

Comment: Try replacing `resstr = strchr( token, '=' );` with `resstr = &token[i];` maybe?

Comment: All those casts in the last couple of lines of code are very undesirable and should be unnecessary.

Comment: Drop `stop` and `i`.  Do `for(reststr = token; *reststr && *reststr == *format++; reststr++) ; if( *reststr == '=' ) ...`.  (Better, omit `reststr` and replace it with `token`.)  But this is probably navel gazing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a lexer generator such as Flex and a simple parser.  [You can use a parser generator for the parser, but doing a hand code parser for your parameter language shouldn't be very hard). The lexer generator will combine all your strtotok functions in an efficient state machine that only examines each input character once.
2. Use a big buffer to read the source file, to minimize the cost of disk reads.  (OS calls are expensive).